# Filter event doesn't update the table at once, must filter it again to display results

Tags: ajax, primefaces

My datatable is built with `LazyDataModel`, so filtering is done by Ajax event `filter`.

The method is called and executed, but the dataTable must be filtered again to show the last filtered results.

If I add `oncomplete="PF('table').filter()"` to the Ajax component, there's an infinite loop.

Pastebin HTML: http://pastebin.com/tmzqFSaE

Pastebin Java (onFilter method): http://pastebin.com/b5tgbWAc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to overwrite the `load` method(s) in `LazyDataModel<T>` and put the necessary filter logic there . The whole point of the lazy model is, that you hold only a portion of the data in memory.

Calling `filter()` on the filter-event will cause an infinite recursive loop.

Comment: Almost getting there... It filters and create the pages, but doesn't change the page. Inside `load` method: `lazyPanoramicaDataModel.setRowCount(filteredByNome.size());` then `lazyPanoramicaDataModel.setPageSize(pageSize);` and return `filteredByNome`.

Comment: The page size is usually fixed or selectable from several predefined values. The `load` method should do two things: (1) load the amount of items at the beginning of the offset that you get as parameters (offset and amount) and return the items(2) determine the total amount of items that fall into the filtered category. You should consult [link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml) and [link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/01/primefaces-datatable-lazy-loading-with-pagination-filtering-and-sorting-using-jpa-criteria-viewscoped.html) for complete examples.